# Picking n random files from a directory

Tags: java, directory

I have a folder containing over 100k folders in it. If I use listFiles() then it takes a lot of time because it returns all the entries present in the folder. What I want is, n random entries from the folder which I will process and will move to a different location.

Comment: This is not a place to ask people to do your job form scratch, show your current code and we will tell you why it does not work properly and how to improve it.

Comment: @Bentaye I am asking to select n files from a folder without preloading the complete directory details in the memory. This is just a small part of my task. So if you know any suitable solution then please suggest it else don't spam here.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious to see what sort of performance you get with `listFiles()`, so I tested. With 100,000 children, I saw a delay of 0.051 seconds. You will likely see this rate hold relatively well (nothing I have found would suggest any substantial increase within Java; any rapid degradation will come natively). While this delay is relatively small, I looked into *how* `listFiles` works to determine if there was any potential improvements that could be made.

### Improvement 1

The first solution is to use `File.list()` as opposed to `File.listFiles()`. If you look at the code for the `listFiles()` method, you can see how Java finds the children of a Folder.

```
    public File[] listFiles() {
        String[] ss = list();
        if (ss == null) return null;
        int n = ss.length;
        File[] fs = new File[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            fs[i] = new File(ss[i], this);
        }
        return fs;
    }
```

The `listFiles()` method takes an array of the names of the children, which are Strings, and creates a File object for each child. The iteration and instantiation of File objects would create an unnecessary overheard for yours task; You only want a single File which would be less expensive if the conversion from a `String[]` to a `File[]` was ignored. Fortunately, the `list();` method is public, so you can use this method instead to obtain a slight performance increase.

A rough test shows that this reduced the time by approximately 25% (when searching a folder with 100,000 children).

### Improvement 2

The next logical step would be to look at the `list()` and see what it does. Here things get a little bit sticky:

```
    public String[] list() {
        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (security != null) {
            security.checkRead(path);
        }
        if (isInvalid()) {
            return null;
        }
        return fs.list(this);
    }
```

Under the assumption you are okay with skipping the security and validation checks, you would want to follow `fs.list(this);` to where it takes you. Following this takes you down a bit of a rabbit hole:

1. `fs.list(this)`
2. `DefaultFileSystem.getFileSystem().list(File f)`
3. `new WinNTFileSystem.list(File f)`

which is where you stop. The .list(File f)`is declared`native` meaning that it has been implemented in native code using JNI. All the way down the line access is restricted meaning

If you are wanting to go as deep as you can possibly go, you could use reflection to gain access to these methods. The lowest level I believe you can go is the native method `WinNTFileSystem.file(File f)`, though I would highly recommend against doing this.

```
/* Setup */

// Get FileSystem from File class
Field fieldFileSystem = File.class.getDeclaredField("fs");
fieldFileSystem.setAccessible(true);
Object fs = fieldFileSystem.get(null);

// Get WinNTFileSystem class
Class<?> classWinNTFileSystem = Class.forName("java.io.WinNTFileSystem");

// Get native `list` method from WinNTFileSystem class
Method methodList = classWinNTFileSystem .getMethod("list", File.class);
methodList.setAccessible(true);


/* Each time you want to invoke the method */
String[] files = (String[]) methodList.invoke(fs, root);
```

The performance upgrade for this varied significantly. At times I saw slightly better than using the previous method while others I saw drastic improvements of over 50%, though I am skeptical of this performance. Using this method you should see at least a  minor increase over `File.list()`. *(The assumption was made that you only create the Method object once and reused it through the code).*

### Note

Short of using keys are file names, you won't see any significant performance increases beyond what I have shown. In order to index a File, as you want, you would need the list as there simply is no native implementation for "get child at index n". You *could* use a key or index as the filename itself, and simply create a new File object using `new File(root, "12353");`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually java has  DirectoryStream interface can be used to iterate over a directory without preloading its content into memory. A sample code for the same is mentioned below.

```
        Path logFolder = Paths.get(windowsClientParentFolder);
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(logFolder)) {
            for (Path entry : stream) {
                String folderName = entry.getFileName().toString();
                //process the folder
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred while reading folders.");
        }
```